# How can I reconstruct a Time series using it AR coefficients in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, autoregressive-model

I have estimated AR coefficients of a time series using "aryule" function in MATLAB. Now I want to obtain the error of the estimated model. I think at first I must reconstruct it. so How can I reconstruct a Time series using it AR coefficients in MATLAB?

Comment: What do you mean by the "error of the estimated model" ?  Do you know the true coefficients that were used to generate the original time series?

Comment: Use Least square method (LS)
Hope that help

Answer (score 1):

If you drive your AR model with white noise, you can generate a time series that has the same power spectral density as the original time series.  But it won't be the same time series.